# PyGame physics simulation for some reason all bodies are moving at the same speed

Tags: python, pygame, physics

I am currently working through some lessons on natural simulations on Khan Academy and am attempting to reproduce their JavaScript code in python. In the code below, I am attempting to simulate gravity and wind on two different bodies of different masses. But, even though in the `apply_force()` method I am dividing by the bodies' mass, when I run the simulation both bodies are moving with the exact same velocity. The wind should be making the smaller body move faster than the larger body, but it is not.

```
#init pygame library
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()

window_width = 800
window_height = 800

FPS = 500

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([window_width, window_height])

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True

#basic vector class class
class Vector2f:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def add(self, v2):
        self.x = self.x + v2.x
        self.y = self.y + v2.y

    def mult(self, v2):
        self.x = self.x * v2.x
        self.y = self.y * v2.y

#mover class
class Mover:
    def __init__(self, mass, position, velocity, acceleration):
        self.mass = mass
        self.position = position
        self.velocity = velocity
        self.acceleration = acceleration

    def apply_force(self, force):
        f = Vector2f((force.x/float(self.mass)), (force.y/float(self.mass)))
        self.acceleration.add(f)

    def update(self):
        self.velocity.add(self.acceleration)
        self.position.add(Vector2f(self.velocity.x, self.velocity.y))
        self.acceleration.mult(Vector2f(0,0))

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (50, 50, 50), (int(round(self.position.x)),                                         int(round(self.position.y))), self.mass)

    def check_edges(self):
        if self.position.x > window_width:
            self.position.x = window_width
            self.velocity.x = self.velocity.x * -1
        elif self.position.x < 0:
            self.position.x = 0
            self.velocity.x = self.velocity.x * -1

        if self.position.y > window_height:
            self.velocity.y = self.velocity.y * -1
            self.position.y = window_height


m_position = Vector2f(30, 30)
m_velocity = Vector2f(0, 0)
m_acceleration = Vector2f(0, 0)

m1 = Mover(30, m_position, m_velocity, m_acceleration)
m2 = Mover(5, m_position, m_velocity, m_acceleration)


#simulation loop
while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    screen.fill((255,255,255))


    wind = Vector2f(.003, 0)
    gravity = Vector2f(0, .005)

    m1.apply_force(wind)
    m1.apply_force(gravity*m1.mass)

    m1.update()
    m1.draw()
    m1.check_edges()

    m2.apply_force(wind)
    m2.apply_force(gravity*m2.mass)

    m2.update()
    m2.draw()
    m2.check_edges()



    pygame.display.flip()


pygame.quit()
```

Furthermore, when I decrease the mass of the smaller mover (`m2`), somehow the speed of `m1` is increasing.

Comment: I don't believe that is the problem; that line is necessary to reset the acceleration each frame.

Comment: Both `m1` and `m2` are *sharing* the same vectors `m_position`, `m_velocity`, and `m_acceleration`.  Everything that updates one of those vectors is therefore seen by both objects.

Comment: @jasonharper This was the issue, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You create vectors for `m_position`, `m_velocity`, and `m_acceleration`. The instance objects `m1` and `m2` are sharing this vectors. The `position`, `velocity` and  `acceleration` attributes refer to the same objects. If you change the attribute of one of the objects, the attributes of the other objects seem to magically change too.

Make copies of the vectors for the arguments when you create the `m1` and `m2` objects:

```py
class Vector2f:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def copy(self):
        return Vector2f(self.x, self.y)

    # [...]
```

```py
m_position = Vector2f(30, 30)
m_velocity = Vector2f(0, 0)
m_acceleration = Vector2f(0, 0)

m1 = Mover(30, m_position.copy(), m_velocity.copy(), m_acceleration.copy())
m2 = Mover(5, m_position.copy(), m_velocity.copy(), m_acceleration.copy())
```

---

Side note: PyGame provides the classes [`pygame.math.Vector2`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2) and [`pygame.math.Vector3`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector3) for two-dimensional and three-dimensional vectors, respectively.